# Accessing R's Environmental Variables from Bash

Tags: r, bash

I'm trying to access R's [environmental variables](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/EnvVar.html) from bash. The installation guide initially lead me to believe that $R_HOME was declared within bash. However, that does not seem to be accurate.

Is there a way to access these environmental variables from bash?

Previous questions have asked how to access these variables from within R, using Sys.getenv() or Sys.setenv(). The focus of this question is to be able to access the information via bash. Simply calling `echo $R_HOME` does not yield the appropriate path in the bash variable.

For example, I am able to get the information using a convoluted method:

```
R_HOME=$(Rscript -e "Sys.getenv('R_HOME')" | grep -Po '".*?"' | sed 's/"//g')
```

So I would receive:
[1] "/usr/lib64/R"

Grep then gives:
"/usr/lib64/R"

And finally sed:
/usr/lib64/R

I would really prefer to figure a way that lets me access ALL the environmental variables without having to go through this process.

Definitions for some of the environmental variables are listed within [R_HOME/etc/Renviron](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html). However, none of them are available in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier than the two earlier answers suggest:

Because `RHOME` is so central, do `R RHOME`:

```
edd@don:~$ R RHOME
/usr/lib/R
edd@don:~$ val=$(R RHOME)
edd@don:~$ echo ${val}
/usr/lib/R
edd@don:~$
```

Essentially all others are available via `R CMD config ...`

```
edd@don:~$ R CMD config --help | head -20
Usage: R CMD config [options] [VAR]

Get the value of a basic R configure variable VAR which must be among
those listed in the 'Variables' section below, or the header and
library flags necessary for linking against R.

Options:
  -h, --help            print short help message and exit
  -v, --version         print version info and exit
      --cppflags        print pre-processor flags required to compile
            a C/C++ file using R as a library
      --ldflags         print linker flags needed for linking a front-end
                        against the R library
      --no-user-files  ignore customization files under ~/.R
      --no-site-files  ignore site customization files under R_HOME/etc

Variables:
  BLAS_LIBS     flags needed for linking against external BLAS libraries
  CC            C compiler command
  CFLAGS        C compiler flags
edd@don:~$
```

Lastly, for a *running R session* you can start one and access it:

```
edd@don:~$ Rscript -e 'cat(Sys.getenv("PATH"))'     # manual break
/home/edd/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:\
/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/gamesedd@don:~$
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's not set in `bash` but you need to use it, why not do:

```
R_HOME=`Rscript --silent -e 'writeLines(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"))'`
echo $R_HOME
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
```

(obviously, I'm on OS X)

You can get all of the `R_` variables thusly:

```
Rscript -e 'for (x in grep("^R_", names(Sys.getenv()), value=TRUE)) writeLines(sprintf("%s=%s", x, Sys.getenv(x)))'
```

and then source the output of that for your `bash` scripts.

Answer (score 1):

No, none of those variables will be available in bash--unless you set them yourself.

You'll probably be interested in `?Startup`, which explains the process behind how R sets the environmental variables:

> Unless --no-environ was given on the command line, R searches for site and user files to process for setting environment variables. The name of the site file is the one pointed to by the environment variable R_ENVIRON; if this is unset, ‘R_HOME/etc/Renviron.site’ is used (if it exists, which it does not in a ‘factory-fresh’ installation). The name of the user file can be specified by the R_ENVIRON_USER environment variable; if this is unset, the files searched for are ‘.Renviron’ in the current or in the user's home directory (in that order).

Note that you can run two scripts that will have different `Renviron` files and thus different environmental variables. I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it's worth keeping in mind that there may not be One True Value for a given variable.

That said, you *could* read in the default `Renviron` and set all the variables yourself:

```
$ R_HOME=`R RHOME`
$ source $R_HOME/etc/Renviron
$ echo $R_PAPERSIZE
a4
```